# Redirect ENTER key to different command (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, keycode

I have a textbox for which I want the space key to be executed every time a person hits the enter key **INSTEAD OF** adding an extra line. I am using the following code but to no avail:

```
txtVerbs.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterkey);
function enterkey(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == 13){event.keyCode == 32}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
txtVerbs.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterkey);
function enterkey(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER){ // you should use the Keyboard constants instead of the hard value
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        txtVerbs.text += ' ';
    }
}
```

`stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents the event from traveling any further, so it will stop any other `KEY_DOWN` event further down the line and should (at least from what I remember) stop the `KEY_UP` from firing as well.

`preventDefault()` cancels the default behavior of an event, if it is possible to be cancelable. If memory serves, the key being pressed is cancelable. If it isn't, however, you could also do a RegEx replace.

```
txtVerbs.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, enterkey);
function enterkey(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER){ // you should use the Keyboard constants instead of the hard value
        txtVerbs.text = txtVerbs.text.replace(/\r?\n/gm, ' ');
    }
}
```

That should match any newline character (it is \r\n on some systems and just \n on others) and replace it with a space

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and explanation, Josh. However, neither seems to work, and there are no errors from the output regarding the code. I also tried replacing stopImmediatePropogation(); with stopPropagation(), but that didn't make a difference.